# How to rewrite email subject in postfix for outgoing mail if From contains specific address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix

I would like to do a simple rewrite (basically, just string replace) in the Subject line for outgoing mail, but only if there is a specific From address in the message. 
I looked at headers_checks, but I cannot understand how it works when you are dealing with more than one header. 
It would be helpful if I could process the outgoing mail using the custom script, but I can't find how to do that in postfix.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it quite simply (in postfix), `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` is the parameter you need, then in the file `/etc/postfix/header_checks` add a line like this:

`/^From: user@domain.com/ FILTER transport:destination`

the `transport:destination`
 line is the most complicated part, the transport is a line you will define in the master.cf, and the destination is where (localhost:port, pipe, etc). You really need to read a bit of the documentation, http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html and http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html will give you a lot more information about how you can pass the mail to your script, as well as the control you can exert over it.